# How do I access new Map() keys and values with .get()

Tags: javascript

I have Function that maps out an Array in to Groups and now I want to access the keys and values in the groups

[image: toDoList Array]

Code to group array with new Map()

```
reduceArray() {
  console.log("this.toDoList", this.toDoList);
  const MapArrayIntoGroups = this.toDoList.reduce(
    (Map, e) => Map.set(e.ID, [...Map.get(e.ID)||[], e]),
    new Map()
  );
  console.log("MapArrayIntoGroups",MapArrayIntoGroups);
  const key = MapArrayIntoGroups.get(); // get Key
  console.log("key",key);
  const value = MapArrayIntoGroups.get(); // value array
  console.log("value",value);
}
```

Here is the result

[image: result of mapping]

I have trying MapArrayIntoGroups.get(value); etc.. with no success.  How do I access those keys, values

Comment: So doing -> `MapArrayIntoGroups.get(1496)` does not get 1496?

Comment: You have to give an argument to `get()` to tell it which element to return.

Comment: Yes get(1496) returns the values in the key. Looks like I will have to use a  for loop. Just curious if the was an easy way I missed

Comment: You could use [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) to get an iterator of keys and values...

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your map with for of:

```
for (const [key, value] of MapArrayIntoGroups) {
  console.log(key)
  console.log(value)
}
```

or forEach:

```
MapArrayIntoGroups.forEach(function(value, key) {
  console.log(key)
  console.log(value)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```js
const key = MapArrayIntoGroups.get(); // get Key
console.log("key",key);
const value = MapArrayIntoGroups.get(); // value array
console.log("value",value);
```

Do like that to get the value if you know *the key*

```js
const key = 1496
const value =MapArrayIntoGroups.get(key);
```

> How do I access those keys, values

```js
//utility function to get keys of each entry
const keys = arrays => arrays.map(array=>array[0]);

// keys([...MapArrayIntoGroups]);// try this to get all keys like an array [1496,...]
```

Thanks @Heretic said in comments that map has Already a method called `keys()`; Which is self-explanatory *get all keys of an map*

```js
Array.from(MapArrayIntoGroups.keys());
//or
[...MapArrayIntoGroups.keys()];
```

Comment: Why would you go through all that to get the keys when `Map` has a [`keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) function? `const keys = Array.from(MapArrayIntoGroups.keys());` or `const keys = [...MapArrayIntoGroups.keys()];` if spreading gives you more frisson.

Comment: I didn't knew that Map has already function to get all keys `keys`; it return *object of type MapIterator* we do spread to get keys. thanks for this method!